# Bash jq with dynamic name

Tags: json, linux, bash, jq

I'm trying to create a script to read the return code from a json from a curl command.

my curl command is:

```
curl -sk 'https://192.168.0.1/custom/getData.php?device=mydevice&object=http--HTTP_v6_Global Index&indicator=http_httpCode&plugin=xxx' | jq '.'
```

The json output is:

```
{
  "device": "mydevice",
  "object": "http--HTTP_v6_Global ",
  "object_descr": "HTTP download of http://192.168.0.1",
  "indicator": "http_httpCode",
  "indicator_descr": null,
  "plugin": "xxx",
  "starttime": 1650468121,
  "endtime": 1650468421,
  "data": {
    "1650468248": {
      "http_httpCode#HTTP Code": 200
    }
  }
}
```

How can read the value `"http_httpCode#HTTP Code"` if `1650468248` is a dynamic value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`to_entries`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries) so you can use `.value` to target the 'unknown' key:

```
jq '.data | to_entries | first | .value."http_httpCode#HTTP Code"'
```

[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/pf6W0zDIUD)

---

Another approach by just 'looping over everything' either with [`..`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RecursiveDescent:..) or [`.[]`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Array/ObjectValueIterator:.%5B%5D):

```
jq '.data | .. | ."http_httpCode#HTTP Code"? // empty'
```

[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/-t_Y3zajz_)

```
jq '.data | .[]."http_httpCode#HTTP Code"'
```

[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/CfLgmlZJB7)

---

They all return `200`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I solved.
This is my solution:

```
jq -r '.data | .[]."http_httpCode#HTTP Code"'
```